# perform sql query on DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datatable

I have a DataTable in C# which I am returning from SQL server. I am passing this datatable to couple separate functions.

Can I send some sort of query directly to the DataTable, instead of looping over all records?

for example

```
set|subset|value
1  |1     |40
1  |2     |30
1  |3     |35
2  |1     |10
2  |2     |15
2  |3     |20
```

how can I do something like `SELECT DISTINCT SET FROM TABLE` and get values `1` and `2`

Comment: Why use SQL on a datatable when you can use LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use LINQ, it's easier.

```
var result = yourTable.AsEnumerable().Select(f => f.Field<int>("Set")).Distinct();
```

Comment: .Select works but Linq is just one rank behind beer in the big list of awesome